# C++ simple class

Tags: c++, oop, class

I started learning C++, classes, objects, structures and more, but I'm having some problems with this.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Owner
{
    public:
        // Getters
        string GetName(){return info.name;}
        int GetAge(){return info.age;}
        short int GetGender(){return info.gender;}

        // Setters
        void SetName(string value){info.name = value;}
        void SetAge(int value){info.age = value;}
        void SetGender(short int value){info.gender = value;}
    private:
        struct info
        {
            string name;
            int age;
            short int gender;
        };
};

class Pet
{
    public:
        // Getters
        string GetName(){return info.name;}
        int GetAge(){return info.age;}
        short int GetGender(){return info.gender;}

        // Setters
        void SetName(string value){info.name = value;}
        void SetAge(int value){info.age = value;}
        void SetGender(short int value){info.gender = value;}
    private:
        struct info
        {
            string name;
            int age;
            short int gender;
        }
};


int main()
{

    // Creating object ...

    cout << "qq" << endl;



    return 0;
}
```

But I get these errors when I try to compile it:

```
In member function 'std::string Owner::GetName()':|
main.cpp|9|error: expected primary-expression before '.' token|
In member function 'int Owner::GetAge()':|
main.cpp|10|error: expected primary-expression before '.' token|
In member function 'short int Owner::GetGender()':|
main.cpp|11|error: expected primary-expression before '.' token|
In member function 'void Owner::SetName(std::string)':|
main.cpp|14|error: expected unqualified-id before '.' token|
In member function 'void Owner::SetAge(int)':|
main.cpp|15|error: expected unqualified-id before '.' token|
In member function 'void Owner::SetGender(short int)':|
main.cpp|16|error: expected unqualified-id before '.' token|
main.cpp|45|error: expected unqualified-id before '}' token|
In member function 'std::string Pet::GetName()':|
main.cpp|30|error: expected primary-expression before '.' token|
In member function 'int Pet::GetAge()':|
main.cpp|31|error: expected primary-expression before '.' token|
In member function 'short int Pet::GetGender()':|
main.cpp|32|error: expected primary-expression before '.' token|
In member function 'void Pet::SetName(std::string)':|
main.cpp|35|error: expected unqualified-id before '.' token|
In member function 'void Pet::SetAge(int)':|
main.cpp|36|error: expected unqualified-id before '.' token|
In member function 'void Pet::SetGender(short int)':|
main.cpp|37|error: expected unqualified-id before '.' token|
||=== Build finished: 13 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

Why does it give me so many errors?

I don't know why, because it is obvious that, for example,

```
 string GetName()
 {
     return info.name;
 }
```

returns a string, from the structure `info.name`

I'm using CodeBlocks.

Comment: You are using structure before it's defined. You also only defined `info` type and haven't instantiated classe's member of type `info`.

Comment: `className.memberName` isn't valid C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're misunderstanding the syntax of the struct keyword, furthermore the actual member variable has to be declared *before* the member functions accessing it. So change your class declarations to something like

```
class Owner
{
private:
    struct
    {
        string name;
        int age;
        short int gender;
    } info;

public:
    // Getters
    string GetName(){return info.name;}
    int GetAge(){return info.age;}
    short int GetGender(){return info.gender;}

    // Setters
    void SetName(string value){info.name = value;}
    void SetAge(int value){info.age = value;}
    void SetGender(short int value){info.gender = value;}
};
```

Comment: Wow, this is interesting, for what i understood, `private` is usually at the top, because there must be some variables, that's c++, but why you put `info` at the end of the struct before `;` , i mean it changes everything ...

Comment: @BrTeam because `struct info { blah... }` declares a TYPE (that is named `struct info`). However, `struct { blah... } info;` declares a VARIABLE of type unnamed struct. And you can't have a TYPE member of a class, only a variable member.

Comment: didn't knew that, c++ is way different, really made a logic into my head, thanks!

Comment: but what if i put the struct outside the classes like a global ?

Comment: "c++ is way different" from what? That's the same rule about struct names in C.

Comment: @BrTeam what do you mean by that? (btw thanks for the accept).

Comment: having structure outside of a class

Comment: @BrTeam yes: `struct something { ... };` then in your class: `struct something info;`

Answer (score 2):

You're declaring the struct as a type (`Owner.info`) instead of as a member (`this->info`). You probably want this:

```
struct OwnerInfo
{
    string name;
    int age;
    short int gender;
};

class Owner {
    // stuff..
private:
    OwnerInfo info;
};
```

Or, the more reasonable version would be just having them there directly instead of inside a pointless `struct`:

```
class Owner {
    // stuff..
private:
    string name;
    int age;
    short int gender;
};
```

Comment: so it is useless to have structure in the class? it is just fine to have it even global?

Comment: @BrTeam I would just leave the `struct` out, since it doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

The declaration:

```
private:
    struct info
    {
        string name;
        int age;
        short int gender;
    };
```

... defines the layout of a nested structure type `info`, much like the definition of the entire class does. However, `info` is now a type nested within Owner, not an instance of that type that is a member of Owner. Instead, try naming the struct Info, then declaring `Info info = new Info();` in the private section of Owner.

Comment: `Info *info` and don't forget to take appropriate actions in dtor. Too much for simple class from my POV. Also, using raw pointer is "old" C++ if you ask me.

Comment: Sorry. I was initially attracted to the question by the C# tag the OP erroneously specified. I haven't coded in C++ for a very long time, but thought it was still simple enough to answer. Apparently not.

Comment: @KeithS, Yes, it works. It's not nearly as user-friendly as a smart pointer, seeing as how C++ has no garbage collector, though.

Answer (score 0):

Well you created a struct and therefor told your compiler "info" is a typ with the following attributes...

You need to declare a variable of the type "info".

```
info personalInfo;
```

Declare it as class member and you can create your Get-er and Set-er.

```
string GetName(){return personalInfo.name;}
```

[More Information](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/structures/)

Comment: to "re declare" ?? haven't heard about this

Comment: redeclare? That's forbidden. Op made a type definition here and did not declare anything to be type "info". He has to declare something of type info and work with it.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a object of struct info. You just cannot access a field of a struct directly without creating an object.. Why do you need the struct at all? try this

```
class Owner
{
    private:
            string name;
            int age;
            short int gender;

    public:
        // Getters
        string GetName(){return this->name;}
        int GetAge(){return this->age;}
        short int GetGender(){return this->gender;}

        // Setters
        void SetName(string value){this->name = value;}
        void SetAge(int value){this->age = value;}
        void SetGender(short int value){this->gender = value;}
};
```